# using stagger animation in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween

I want to animate array of meshes but properties are not recognized

```
tl.staggerFrom(array,2,{"position.y":-100})
```

position.y doesnt change 
when I use console.log(array[0].position.y) it gives the the inital value of position.y

how can I use stagger animation in threejs meshes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using GSAP (TweenMax), and that library requires you to use shallow objects as its animation parameter. This means you can't animate a variable that's 2+ levels deep; you can't ask it to animate `array[0].position.y`, but you *can* ask it to animate `position.y`. With this in mind, consider the following:

```
// Save reference to all positions into a new array
var allPositions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    allPositions.push(array[i].position);
}

// Now use the shallower objects to animate the y attribute
tl.staggerFrom(allPositions,2,{y: -100});
```

Comment: this will only change the "y" in the allPosition array it will not change the position of the mesh

Comment: @eomer At first glance it may seem that way, but you're saving a *reference* to the position vector, not generating a new vector. So when you change the `y` attribute, it'll actually affect the mesh position. Try it, you'll see that it works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with using proxy
I create a new proxy instance for every mesh and in its set property I just do what I want to do with it and add the proxy to an array and use that array in stagger

for ex:

```
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
    let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    let proxy = new Proxy({positionY:null},{
           set(target,key,value){
                    target[key] = value;
                    if(target[key] !== null){
                         mesh.position.y = target.positionY
                    }
                     return true;
                },
                get(target,key){
                    return target[key];
                }
            })
proxy.positionY = 0
aarray.push(proxy)
}
tl.staggerFrom(aarray,5,{positionY:-100})
```